# Get parent's scope array in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Sorry if it is a duplicate but I can't find the solution.

I have the following:

```
appDrct.directive('jsonArray', [function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            console.log(scope.$parent.categories);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Which gives me an empty array (categories is not empty). If I print this: `console.log(scope.$parent);`, I can see my array with the items inside! Why is that? And how can I get my array?

Edit:
It is in a modal view...

```
div(class="modal-header")
   div(json-array='categories')
```

Comment: Then that should work...also, `scope.categories` should work as well - the scope will look up to the parent

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well? Something else is going on that we are not seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use just `scope.categories`...

`scope.$parent.categories` - would be right only if you have `scope: true` for your directive

Comment: Still getting an empty array !?!?!

Comment: @ncohen probably you have something wrong somewhere else: http://plnkr.co/edit/wXHlwZEhf7OnLlXRF8vS?p=preview

Comment: Could it be because the div(json-array) is in a modal view?

Comment: @ncohen yes, in case if you are using ui-bootstrap modal, by default view scope would be created as child of $rootScope - so there would be no access to your scope. but you can change this behaviour by passing you scope into modal configuration (then scope for modal would be created as a child of passed scope)

Comment: Oh that's it... I'm using ui-bootstrap. Could you please give me an example of how you would do it? I didn't completely understand

Comment: I tried your example without scope and it still works! My problem might be because categories is taken from the local DB? But how is it possible that I can see it when I print console.log(scope.$parent)?

Comment: @ncohen you are missing something - just tried to be sure, it is not working without scope parameter